# How to make rss feed show only one item per day in android

Tags: android, parsing, listview, xml-parsing

I have an Rss feed that I am parsing into a list view.  I would like to make this app show only one item per day.  For example, when the user logs into the app i want them to only see Day one item from list view, then when they log in the next day they will see Day one, and Day two from list view.  How would I go about achieving this?  Here is the code I am using for this

Main Activity

```
  public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.cpcofc.org/devoapp.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "item";
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_DESC, KEY_NAME, KEY_COST}, new int[] {
                    R.id.desciption, R.id.name, R.id.cost});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Collections.reverse(menuItems);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
 }
```

RSS parser

```
 public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
 }
```

Here is what the view looks like now as is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Store the day when they first login in a preference (or some other on disk storage).  When you load the data into the array list, find out how long its been since that first login by using standard date functions, and only add that many items to the list.

Comment: Sounds like that would work great for me, do you know of a tutorial or anything that would show me how to do that, I have never worked with those functions so not familiar with them

Comment: Look at the SharedPreferences class and the SharedPreferences.Editor class.  Those are how you read/write a preference.  You only want to write your preference the first time you run the app, the way to do that is to check if it exists, and write it if not.  For the date manipulation, just call Date() to get todays date, and compare dates by converting them to milliseconds using Date.getTime(), subtracting, and dividing by the number of milliseconds in a day.  Or if you want it to roll over at midnight, use a Calendar to get the time at midnight of the current day.

Comment: thank you this gives me a great starting point and direction to go

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have any code snippets or anything that might give me a good example of how to use this in my app do you